# How to simplify sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query --

```
select * from main_iteminstance where master_id=33568
  or tv_series_id  in 
(select id from main_iteminstance where master_id=33568)
```

How would this best be simplified?

Basically, what I am trying to get is:

```
ids = select id from main_iteminstance where master_id=33568
child_ids = select id from main_iteminstance where tv_series_id in ids
my_answer = ids + child_ids
```

Comment: `WHERE master_id=33568 OR (tv_series_id=id AND master_id=33568)` This is your first query,no need for a subquery,but the second condition is superfluous

Comment: Show some data with the desired results.

Comment: @Mihai The second condition may be required, but only if there are rows where the id and the tv_series_id are different and the master_id is not 33568 and there are rows where the master_id is 33568 with the id being the same as the tv_series_id in the first rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at this further, the subquery is performing the lookup where the master_id is the same value of the parent query.  This means the condition with the `tv_series_id` is superfluous as it will only return results that have already been found in the parent.

Your most simple resultset would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   main_iteminstance 
WHERE  master_id=33568
```

Unless you're looking for `tv_series_id` to match `id` `where master_id != 33568`

---

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad5ab/1)

This example demonstrates where tv_series_id matches id's where the master_id != 33568.  If that's not desired, you can remove the OR and everything after.

Comment: No, the tv_series_id will never be 33568. Note that in the second subquery I'm selecting the `id` from the main_iteminstance.

Comment: no I didn't do the minus one, I left a comment (I never downvote).

Comment: @David542 if you're always looking for `master_id=33568` then the OR part of your query (`tv_series_id` matching `id`) may never be needed.  It's only necessary if `master_id != 33568`

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to show only where master_id isn't the one you were previously looking for (but I'm not sure that's what you're after).  It seems like you have a data hierarchy here (parent/child relationships), but I'm not quite certain how the data looks

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to join the table on itself:

```
SELECT Master.*
FROM main_iteminstance Master
INNER JOIN main_iteminstance Child
ON Child.master_id = 33568 AND ((Master.id = Child.id) OR (Master.tv_series_id = Child.id))
```

Comment: This would be the same as doing: `select * from main_iteminstance where master_id=33568`

Comment: Good point.  In fact correlated sub-queries are sometimes converted internally into this form.  I became aware of this when some early DBMS products did so incorrectly (which is what called this to my attention so many years ago).

Comment: @David542, actually not.  'select * from main_iteminstance where master_id=33568' is a very different query.  What the questioner is trying to do is select all rows who's id or tv_series_id matches that of another row who's master_id is 33568.  Your query just returns the rows who's master_id is 33568.  This is only the same if the only rows that have 33568 have them in all three columns.

Comment: @KenClement (I'm the questioner) I suppose, but the AND clause is only going to be correct if it's referring to itself, so in the above case it can be disposed of.

Comment: @David542, The query that Chris gives and the query I gave would be equivalent and as I noted some DBMS's will convert the sub-query version into the self-join version internally.  HOWEVER neither of these is equivalent to 'select * from mainiteminstance where master_id=33568'.  The later query only returns the same result set under very peculiar circumstances - but not in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a correlated sub-query as shown below:

```
select * 
from main_iteminstance as m
where exists (
    select *
    from main_iteminstance as s
    where (m.id = s.id or m.id = s.tv_series_id)
    and s.master_id=33568)
```

How this query performs versus the one you provided depends on a lot of things but it is more maintainable and clearer since everything is specified in a single place.